# What gets past the bluegrass bulge?

Tags: english, word-property

Sort of in the style of that old classic, ‘What goes through the green glass door?’

What gets past the bluegrass bulge?

- Blue does, but green doesn’t.
- Grass does, but glaze doesn’t.
- Bulge does, but door doesn’t.
- Poem does, but muse doesn’t.
- Conversation does, but talk doesn’t.
- Gel does, but official doesn’t.
- Chin does, but tongue doesn’t.
- Sticking does, but stuck doesn’t.
- Mistake does, but miss doesn’t.
- Nomad does, but rover doesn’t.
- Peeping does, but loom doesn’t.
- Tall does, but small doesn’t.
- Morn does, but evening doesn’t.
- Detestable does, but foul doesn’t.

What gets past the bluegrass bulge?

Hint 1:

> Each combination is attested at least twice, on both sides.

Hint 2:

> There’s more linguistics involved than in the previous one.

Hint 3:

> I didn’t count things that were part of affricate consonants.

Hint 4:

> Vowel doesn’t get past, and that makes sense in 1 out of 3 cases. Vowels doesn’t either, but that makes sense in 2 out of 3 cases. Neither gets past for the same reason, though.

**Hint 5:**

> You *might* say that part of the solution is the opposite of the original solution; there the IPA has nothing to do with it. The third referred to in the previous hint is the same. But the last third does.

Comment: I’m not sure what other tags to add, because most I could add would be hints outright. Maybe after the question is answered?

Comment: Pretty sure you're safe to add the 'word-property' tag. (Done!) :)

Comment: The etiquette is to leave the question as it was when the correct answer was given.

Comment: Perhaps, but I’m very new to this SE, so any help is welcome :D Also, I changed up the hints and added a few examples.

Comment: Does the solution involve some knowledge of IPA beyond what you may learn without taking linguistics classes?

Comment: @Displayname Linguistics classes definitely aren’t necessary, but Wikipedia can certainly help.

Comment: I don't get hint 4: maybe you meant "consonant"s? Also that hint is not grammatically correct, but maybe that's an hint too...

Comment: For hint 4, neither has two common pronunciations (nie-ther and nee-ther) does that matter? Also what do you mean by "gets past for the same reason" (if it's the same reason why doesn't "vowels" get past as well or vice versa?)

Comment: @BennettBernardoni Sorry, I meant that neither ‘vowels’ nor ‘vowel’ gets past, and neither of them get past for the same reason.

Comment: @melfnt I think "vowel" and "vowels" in hint 4 are considered as string of letters there, not as objects.

Comment: @justhalf indeed, I understood it from their last comment

Comment: Can you please add another hint? It has been a while and the bounty did not help

Comment: @melfnt certainly, although this one’s a bit blatant.

Comment: @Fivesideddice apparently it isn't can you please post your solution (or add another hint)?

Answer (score 4):

A partial answer. I really don't have much but maybe it'll help someone.

> Hint two suggests that this is linguistics based, so I translated everything to IPA (using American pronunciation. Not sure if that matters). Here are all the pairs.
>
>  blu / grin
>  græs / gleɪz
>  bʌlʤ / dɔr
>  ˈpoʊəm / mjuz
>  ˌkɑnvərˈseɪʃən / tɔk
>  ʤɛl / əˈfɪʃəl
>  ʧɪn / tʌŋ
>  ˈstɪkɪŋ / stʌk
>  mɪsˈteɪk / mɪs
>  ˈnoʊˌmæd / ˈroʊvər
>  ˈpipɪŋ / lum
>  tɔl / smɔl
>  mɔrn / ˈivnɪŋ
>  dɪˈtɛstəbl / faʊl
>
>  I tried for a while, but was not able to find any sort of pattern here. Some interesting things to note are that tall and small are different despite being very similar, and mistake is just miss with an added "take" (maybe suggesting that the bluegrass bulge words need to have some phoneme combination).
>
>  Hint 1: Each combination is attested at least twice, on both sides.
>  Again this makes me thing it has something to do with phoneme combinations
>
>  Hint 3: I didn’t count things that were part of affricate consonants.
>  Another thing suggesting that it has to do with IPA, but I don't know enough about linguistics to figure this one out.

Comment: I hope this isn’t too presumptuous, but I’ve put up a new hint :D

Comment: Sorry I don't consider this answer satisfactory enough to award the bounty: tomorrow you will receive half of the prize.

Comment: Oh, I don't think I even deserve half the prize. Most of my work was just translating into ipa which was heavily suggested by the hints.

Comment: I did try out hint 4, but I wasn't able to spot any patterns